# How to handle a off-topic question that has a (potentially) very good on-topic question beneath it?

Tags: discussion

While looking at [Poor man's manner of conducting Agile Scrum/kanban/lean/XP software development philosophies/practices while remotely working online over the internet](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/31576/poor-mans-manner-of-conducting-agile-scrum-kanban-lean-xp-software-development), one might see that there's a very good question on the lines of "how to practice Scrum / Kanban remotely", not necessarily focused on the tools.

However, it'd greatly change the question, making it only a resemblance of the original (off topic) question.

Should the community completely rephrase the question to make it on-topic or close it, suggesting a new question to be raised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fundamentally a software recommendation question, and also a “freeware” shopping question that’s trying to work around a deeper organizational or budgeting dysfunction. Editing it enough to be on topic would change the entire basis of the question and divorce it from the OP’s current situation. I personally don’t think this particular question can be salvaged, but if there’s a related question buried in there that would be on topic then it could be asked as a new question.